# Best way to bulk prepend a random number to filenames?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting, filenames

Alternatively, is there a way to sort files randomly in file explorer?

Ideally I'd like to do this without installing python environment. Perhaps with a nice clean batch file, or  I have searched the internets to no avail so far, though I have found several methods for randomizing the names of each file...

I did find this: [Bash script to prepend a random number to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175302/bash-script-to-prepend-a-random-number-to-all-files) which is sort of what I'd like to do, but not exactly. I need to preserve the original filenames. I just want a simple number prefix. ie 7, 560, 380, or whatever, and then a space and/or hyphen. Not a long string of characters. Also that script is for bash..

Please let me know if you need more clarification of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Your\Path" -File | Rename-Item -NewName { "$(Get-Random -Max 1000)" + $_.Name }
```

Comment: This is fantastic and answers my question! I had a bit of a problem getting the prefix to be not so long, and between x & y, but I'm sure I'll figure it out!

PowerShell

Copy
Get-Random
   [-SetSeed <Int32>]
   [[-Maximum] <Object>]
   [-Minimum <Object>]
   [-Count <Int32>]
   [<CommonParameters>]

Comment: yes I found the documentation right after I wrote that..

Comment: Ok, so here's a weird question that is tangentially related.

I knew to put a separator (between the filename and the randomly generated prefix)  in the script.. ie 
'Get-ChildItem "C:\Your\Path" -File | Rename-Item -NewName { "$(Get-Random -Max 99999)" + " - " + $_.Name }'
 However I was too excited and just used the example script... Now I've got a bunch of numbers directly in front of the files, all which start with alpha char if that helps. Is there any way to place a separator now?

Comment: Regex to the rescue `C:\Your\Path" -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '^(\d+)', '$1 - ' }`

Answer (score 0):

This will rename all file names in the folder randomly between 500 to 10000 and the file extension will be preserved.

```
Get-ChildItem "F:\01 System Files\Desktop\test\" -File | Rename-Item -NewName { "$(Get-Random -Min (500) -Max 10000)" + $_.extension }
```